# React show loading spinner while DOM is rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a list with items that first loads 30 items and if the user clicks on "Load All", rest of the items are shown:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         |
|                           List                          |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                       Load All Button                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

When the list is big (more than 1K items) the rendering of the "Load All" step takes some time and meanwhile the DOM is stuck and not responsive.

What is the right way to tap into React's lifecycle events so that upon clicking the button it will change to a loading spinner and when the list is fully rendered and ready it will change back ?

I have tried separating the two parts (list and button) to two components and wrap them in a parent component that holds a "loading" and then changing the state in the List `componentDidUpdate` function, but it didn't work

### jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wh4z60m6/4/

Comment: Why not just load the next 30 instead of "Load All?" If it's slow on your development PC, it will very likely be significantly slower to load all items on tablets, phones, slower PCs, laptops, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Rendering in React is synchronous, which means nothing else can run alongside it.

You could render your list progressively since the user's screen probably can't display more than a hundred items at a time.

Also, note that rendering thousands of items is much slower in the development build than in the production build of React.

**EDIT:** Another option would be to first render the loader, then render your list items on the next frame. The loader will be displayed until the list items have finished rendering.

```js
React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            loading: false,
            showAll: false,
        };
    },

    _showAll: function() {
        this.setState({ showAll: true, loading: true }, function() {
            // Using setTimeout here ensures that the component will wait until
            // the next frame before trying to render again.
            this.setTimeout(function() {
                this.setState({ loading: false });
            }.bind(this), 1000 / 60);
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        var amount = (this.state.showAll && !this.state.loading) ? 100000 : 3;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this._showAll}>
                    {this.state.loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Show all'}
                </button>
                {items.slice(0, amount).map(renderItem)}
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: I wasn't aware setState takes a callback, cool. However, this did not exactly solve my problem. Please have a look at the JSfiddle I added to the question

Comment: The button text should change while the DOM is loading, but it's not

Comment: @Michael You're trying to render your thousands of components **at the same time** as you're trying to display the `Loading...` label. You should only instanciate them and render them once `this.state.showAll && !this.state.loading` evaluates to true. I've updated my answer.

Comment: When you do this

    `_showAll: function() {
        this.setState({ showAll: true, loading: true }, function() {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
        }.bind(this));
      },`

You set the state for loading to true and IMMEDIATELY set it to false. So the "Loading..." never shows...

If you had a getItems() Promise to get your items you could do something like

    `this.setState({ loading: true });
    getItems().then(
        this.setState({ loading: true });
    );`

But you are using a simple slice so...nothing much you can do except what @Morhaus proposed.

Comment: did you finally managed to tackle it in an efficient way? and how? thanks

Comment: You have mentioned this.setTimeout for setting timeout to change status. What you have considered setTimeout is method in current class ? there should be no 'this 'there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class with a more recent, React 16 example (with comments inline for clarity):

```
class People extends Component {
   state = {
      rows: [],
      loaded: false
   }
   /* lifecycle hook - keeping mind we are manipulating the DOM */
   /* within the component so we need to know the component/dom is ready */
   componentDidMount(){
      let self = this;
      /* returns a fetch() call stored in context passed down */
      /* through a higher order component */
      this.props.context.getPeople() 
        .then(json => { self.setState({rows:json.rows, loaded: true}); })
        /* Notice that loaded is set to true in the state object */
   }

   loading = () => (
      <div className={this.state.loaded?'ajax-loaded':'ajax-loading'}>LOADING</div>
      /* The class ajax-loaded -- you guessed it, hides the div */
      /* The thing to always keep in mind -- when state changes, things happen! */
   );
   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               {this.loading()}
               {this.state.rows.map(row => ( <div>{row.first} {row.last}</div>) )}
               {/* Again, when state changes, things happen! */}
           </div>
       )
   }
}
```